# Websocket randomly goes into aborted state?

Tags: c#, websocket

I am using Chrome Websockets to connect to a C# server app, chrome seems to abort the connection on an arbitrary basis and I get an exception thrown at the C# server, `The communication object cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted`.

I have been hearing about Unobserved Exceptions and that apparently I must catch them somehow, any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Sockets die; web-sockets die pretty frequently, relatively speaking (based on what happens on a few of our web-socket servers). Re "unobserved exceptions" - the trick there is simply: *to observe them*. You might find your web-sockets are more stable if you send a heart-beat message periodically. The newer web-sockets API actually includes a special frame for that exact purpose, but IIRC some browsers don't respect it, so I just use a small regular message. You can then use this same heart-beat to check for zombie connections: if you code the client to always respond to the heart-beat, and you send a heart-beat every (say) 5 minutes, you can simply kill any connections that haven't replied to you in over 10 minutes: they are zombies.

Comment: The problem is that this happens randomly on a new (<1 minute) connection. Any steps I could take towards tracking the problem?

Comment: @user well: are you sure people aren't simply navigating away? It could also be a broken web-sockets impl

Comment: I am testing it locally, there are no "people"

Comment: @user2489890 and when testing locally, what kind of time interval does it take before dying? also: how confident are you in the  specific implementation of rfc6455 (or whichever hybi/hixie version(s) are being supported)

Comment: There is no specific interval it will just die occasionally (very occasionally) seems to be because of a bad packet transmitted. I have no idea whether the websocket version is being supported.

Comment: @user2489890 if one end of this sends an *invalid* packet, then sure: it'll die - it is *required* to; what web-sockets implementation are you using at the server? I use web-sockets a lot, and mine are *usually* fine for ages. Are you sure it isn't simply a bad network, intermittently severing the connection?

Comment: What is the best C# websocket implementation that currently exists? Maybe I'm better off using Alchemy

Comment: @user2489890 in all honesty, I don't know; I'll have to read the alchemy code; we rolled our own, but we do crazy stuff like that ;p